# scilab - Implementing log function on images

Tags: image-processing, scilab

I want to apply a log function to images. But it fails showing this error: `function is not defined on this type of argument`.

```
uk=imread('image.jpg');
result=log(uk(:,:,1));
```

Comment: make sure your image is converted to gray-scale

Comment: No , I need to get the log result for the three RGB channels

Comment: what is the error you get? Maybe you are using a log function that doesn't take a matrix of values just a scalar? also when you are using log you need to make sure you don't have any zeros in the image because log(0)=undifine so better to do log(uk(:,:,1) + ones(:,:))

Comment: the error is the function log is not defined on this type of argument. I tried to add 1 to the image but the same error remains.Besides , when I apply log on simple matrix , it runs but when I applied log on image It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that `imread` returns a matrix of `uint8` type. To apply `log`, you should convert it to `double`. There are at least 2 ways to do this, one built in, and one from SIVP:

```
clc;
clear;
im = imread("d:\Attila\PROJECTS\Scilab\Stackoverflow\mixer_crop.jpg");
//imshow(im);
disp(typeof(im(:,:,1)),"Original type:");

//use double
M = double(im(:,:,1));
disp(typeof(M),"Modified type:");
result=log(M);
//imshow(uint8(M));

//use im2double
M2 = im2double(im);
disp(typeof(M2(:,:,1)),"Modified type 2:");
result=log(M2(:,:,1));
//imshow(im2uint8(M2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . In fact , my code works after I convert the matrix to double and I add 1 to all